# FileNotFoundException when connecting to Postgres database

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql, filenotfoundexception

I am getting a *fileNotFoundException* when I try to connect to my postgres database.
Her is a sample of the code.

```
connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=MMEData;User Id=postgres;Password=nH9Ummg5;";

dbConn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);  //This constructor is when I get the exception
```

---

Here is the exception I am getting:

{"File or assembly name Mono.Security, or one of its dependencies, was not 
found. Mono.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756"}

---

- I copied the `npsql.dll` file to the application's directory and afterwards made a reference to it.
- I also copied the rest of the files from a zip called *'Npgsql-2.2.0-net45.zip'*.
- I have the using npgsql; statement.

I am running pgAdmin III at the same time and in it I connected the server. The Database name is MMEData.

I am running application and postgres on the same (local) machine and on the default port (5432).

Anyone any idea what I am missing?

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Sorry,just edited it

Comment: Sounds like npsql.dll has a dependency on mono.security. For a quick test, copy all assemblies in Npgsqp-2.2.0-net45.zip into the output folder (probably bin\Debug) and try again.

Comment: You could use nuget to install the reference to the postgres client. Would save a lot of the above hassle. The library is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/ To install follow the instruction on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please add reference name called Mono.Security dll in your project solution it could be avoid this type of errors

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy the library Mono.Security.dll to the application's directory and afterwards made a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and my solution was to add Mono.security.dll as a reference to my project, after that the connection to PostgreSQL database was fine.
I downloaded the nuget package.
I renamed it as a zip file.
I extracted Mono.security.dll to my project.
I added it as a reference with always copy to directory.
I compiled my project and runned it and it was ok.